# Transformer Java XML CDATA Duplicate Lines

Tags: java, xml, transformer-model

I am using transformer in JDK 7 to write out some XML and I have in the CDATA a freemarker template as follows:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="no"?>
<fileExport append="false" automaticExport="false" automaticExportWithErrors="true" exportDir="C:\Users\bÃ¤nn\Desktop" exportFileName="&lt;date&gt; &lt;time&gt; &lt;barcode&gt;" exportType="Excel" splitFiles="false">
  <exportTemplate><![CDATA[Date,RackBarcode,Row,Col,tubeBarcode,OrientationBarcode
<#list racks as rack>
<#list rack.containers as container>
${scandate?datetime},${rack.barcode},${container.textRow},${container.col + 1},${container.barcode},${rack.orientationBarcode}
</#list>
</#list>]]></exportTemplate>
  <scanTimeQuestionsTemplate><![CDATA[<#if scanTimeQuestionsEnabled>
Scan Time Questions

<#list scanTimeQuestions as question>
${question.shortName} : ${question.answer}
</#list>

</#if>]]></scanTimeQuestionsTemplate>
  <excelExportTemplate writeHeader="true">
    <excelExportColumn columnDataFormatting="d/M/yyyy HH:mm" columnDataFromString="DATETIME" columnHeader="Scan Time"/>
    <excelExportColumn columnDataFormatting="" columnDataFromString="RACK_BARCODE" columnHeader="Rack Barcode"/>
    <excelExportColumn columnDataFormatting="" columnDataFromString="ORIENTATION_BARCODE" columnHeader="Orientation Barcode"/>
    <excelExportColumn columnDataFormatting="" columnDataFromString="TUBE_ROW_TEXT" columnHeader="Tube Row"/>
    <excelExportColumn columnDataFormatting="" columnDataFromString="TUBE_COLUMN" columnHeader="Tube Column"/>
    <excelExportColumn columnDataFormatting="" columnDataFromString="TUBE_BARCODE" columnHeader="Tube Barcode"/>
    <excelExportColumn columnDataFormatting="d/M/yyy HH:mm:ss" columnDataFromString="DATETIME" columnHeader="Scan Datetime"/>
  </excelExportTemplate>
</fileExport>


</#if>

]]></scanTimeQuestionsTemplate>
  <excelExportTemplate writeHeader="false">
    <excelExportColumn columnDataFormatting="d/M/yyyy HH:mm" columnDataFromString="DATETIME" columnHeader="Scan Time"/>
    <excelExportColumn columnDataFormatting="" columnDataFromString="RACK_BARCODE" columnHeader="Rack Barcode"/>
    <excelExportColumn columnDataFormatting="" columnDataFromString="ORIENTATION_BARCODE" columnHeader="Orientation Barcode"/>
    <excelExportColumn columnDataFormatting="" columnDataFromString="TUBE_ROW_TEXT" columnHeader="Tube Row"/>
    <excelExportColumn columnDataFormatting="" columnDataFromString="TUBE_COLUMN" columnHeader="Tube Column"/>
    <excelExportColumn columnDataFormatting="" columnDataFromString="TUBE_BARCODE" columnHeader="Tube Barcode"/>
  </excelExportTemplate>
</fileExport>
```

However when I write this out on a windows computer the transformer is adding an extra \r into the outputted CDATA so I have:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="no"?>
<fileExport append="false" automaticExport="false" automaticExportWithErrors="false" exportDir="C:\Users\benn\Desktop" exportFileName="" exportType="text" splitFiles="false">
  <exportTemplate><![CDATA[Date,RackBarcode,Row,Col,tubeBarcode,OrientationBarcode

<#list racks as rack>

<#list rack.containers as container>

${scandate?datetime},${rack.barcode},${container.textRow},${container.col + 1},${container.barcode},${rack.orientationBarcode}

</#list>

</#list>

]]></exportTemplate>
  <scanTimeQuestionsTemplate><![CDATA[<#if scanTimeQuestionsEnabled>

Scan Time Questions



<#list scanTimeQuestions as question>

${question.shortName} : ${question.answer}

</#list>



</#if>

]]></scanTimeQuestionsTemplate>
  <excelExportTemplate writeHeader="false">
    <excelExportColumn columnDataFormatting="d/M/yyyy HH:mm" columnDataFromString="DATETIME" columnHeader="Scan Time"/>
    <excelExportColumn columnDataFormatting="" columnDataFromString="RACK_BARCODE" columnHeader="Rack Barcode"/>
    <excelExportColumn columnDataFormatting="" columnDataFromString="ORIENTATION_BARCODE" columnHeader="Orientation Barcode"/>
    <excelExportColumn columnDataFormatting="" columnDataFromString="TUBE_ROW_TEXT" columnHeader="Tube Row"/>
    <excelExportColumn columnDataFormatting="" columnDataFromString="TUBE_COLUMN" columnHeader="Tube Column"/>
    <excelExportColumn columnDataFormatting="" columnDataFromString="TUBE_BARCODE" columnHeader="Tube Barcode"/>
  </excelExportTemplate>
</fileExport>
```

So basically \r\n is becoming \r\r\n - I've seen some messages about Xalan doing this but I'm using whatever JDK 7 provides as the back engine; has anybody seen this and is there a property I can set to stop transformer putting an extra line break in my CDATA>

Answer (score 1):

I  have seen some verbose work-arounds (search "xalan newline"), so what I would do:

1. Ensure that the source has only Unix line endings `\n` (editor setting).
2. `System.setProperty("file.encoding", "\n");`

Probably 1. suffices, as 2. is ugly.